# Algebra II: Cosine (Amplitude, Midline, Period)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

**Question:** The volume of water in a tank varies periodically. At $t=0$ it is at its maximum of $520$ gallons and at $t=10$ it is at its minimum of $100$ gallons.

I need to find the period which is know can be find by dividing $2\pi$ by the frequency.

I know that the amplitude if $210$ and the midline is $y=310$.

I am stuck on how to find the period.

Comment: I think they want you to say that the period is $20$, but I don't see how we know that the time it takes to go from the minimum to the maximum is the same as the time to go from the maximum to the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

From your title, it seems that you are trying to fit a cosine curve.

$$y = A\cos (Bt+C)+D$$

$D$ is the midline, $310$ and $A$, the amplitude is indeed $210$.

$$y = 210\cos (Bt+C))+310$$

When $t=0$, we have $y=520$, now you can solve for $C$.

The only unknown variable now is $B$, of which you can recover using what happens when $t=100$.

After which, you can compute period as $\frac{2\pi}{|B|}$.